# Should I return an empty dict instead of None?

Tags: python

I have a method that currently returns `None` or a `dict`.

```
result,error = o.apply('grammar')
```

The caller currently has to check for the existence of two keys to decide what kind of object was returned.

```
if 'imperial' in result:
    # yay
elif 'west' in result:
    # yahoo
else:
    # something wrong?
```

Because result can be `None`, I'm thinking of returning an empty dict instead, so the caller does not need to check for that. What do you think ?

For comparison, in the `re` module, the result of calling `match` can result in `None`.

```
p = re.compile('\w+')
m = p.match( 'whatever' )
```

But in this case, `m` is an object instance. In my case, I am returning a dict which should either be empty or have some entries.

Comment: I actually feel the `p.match` interface is slightly broken in this regard. I wish it returned a `False` evaluating match object instead of `None`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes I think returning an empty dict (or where applicable an empty list) is preferable to returning None as this avoids an additional check in the client code.

EDIT:
Adding some code sample to elaborate:

```
def result_none(choice):
    mydict = {}
    if choice == 'a':
        mydict['x']  = 100
        mydict['y']  = 1000
        return mydict
    else:
        return None

def result_dict(choice):
    mydict = {}
    if choice == 'a':
        mydict['x']  = 100
        mydict['y']  = 1000
    return mydict

test_dict = result_dict('b')
if test_dict.get('x'):
    print 'Got x'
else:
    print 'No x'

test_none = result_none('b')
if test_none.get('x'):
    print 'Got x'
else:
    print 'No x'
```

In the above code the check `test_none.get(x)` throws an **AttributeError** as
result_none method can possibly return a None. To avoid that I have to add an
additional check and might rewrite that line as:
`if test_none is not None and test_none.get('x')` which is not at all needed
if the method were returning an empty dict. As the example shows the check `test_dict.get('x')`  works fine as the method `result_dict` returns an empty dict.

Comment: I agree. The only time `None` should be returned in these cases is if there is some meaning beyond 'no answers' that needs to be conveyed.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to return the dict from `result_none` (although it doesn't really affect the behavior of your example).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure of the context of this code, but I'd say returning None suggests that there was somehow an error and the operation could not be completed. Returning an empty dictionary suggests success, but nothing matched the criteria for being added to the dictionary.

I come from a completely different background (C++ Game Development) so take this for what it's worth:

For performance reasons though, might be nice to return None and save whatever overhead, though minimal, may be involved in creating an empty dictionary. I find that, generally, if you're using a scripting language, you're not concerned about the performance of that code. If you were, you probably wouldn't be writing that feature in said language unless required for some unavoidable reason.

Comment: I would probably throw an exception if an error was encountered (as oppose to returning None). I believe that is the pythonic way.

Answer (score 3):

After more thought, I think returning an empty `dict` might be more Pythonic. **A good rule of thumb might be to always return an empty container if you write a function/method which returns a container**. Several examples of this behavior:

```
"".split() == []
filter(lambda a:False, [1,2]) == []
range(1, -1) == []
re.findall('x', '') = []
```

In contrast if you are trying to get a single object, you have no choice but to return `None` I suppose. So I guess `None` is like the empty container for single objects! Thanks to KennyTM for arguing some sense into me :D

Comment: `.get` does not "return" a `dict` here.

Comment: Yes it returns a value or None by default.

Comment: @zeekay: No I mean `{'a': 1}.get('a')` returns `1`, not a dict. Also, notice that `None.get('b')` is an error, which suggests `None` should *not* be returned in OP's code :).

Comment: `{'a': {'b': 1}}.get('a')` would return a `dict`. `None` has no `get` method, so I fail to see the point. What I'm saying is that plenty of stuff returns `None`.

Comment: @zeekay: `.get` returns None because it can return other things as well. In OP's question, the only valid return value is a dict besides None. There are plenty of stuff that returns a non-None empty value too, e.g. `"".split() == []`, `"a".find("b") == -1`, `filter(lambda a:False, [1,2]) == []`, `range(1, -1) == []`, etc.

Comment: @zeekay: The point is if `result` in OP's question is None, then `result.get("west")` is error.

Comment: @KennyTM Is doing `If result:` hard? I think it's is simple and readable. I suppose it's all a matter of taste, but I can't think of any situation where I've ever returned an empty container or seen an empty container returned outside of initial object instantiation. One of the things I like about Python is it's consistency. People should write code that is predictable. Returning `{}` just seems weird to me.

Comment: @zeekay: No it's not hard, but OP's point is *so the caller does not need to check for that*. And how is returning `{}` unpredictable?

Comment: It's a matter of taste, as you pointed out both approaches are taken. I don't see any reason to shield the caller (`if result and result.get('a'):`). You either save 1-2 lines in the function or 1-2 lines when it's called. Maybe it's more sensible to return a `dict`? I guess it depends on the context. `re.findall` will return an empty list, whereas `re.search` returns `None`. I can't really make up my mind now which is better.

Comment: @KennyTM actually the more I think about it the more I think you are right. I think the consistent thing to do is to return `{}`. If you have a function which you expect to return a container with 0 or more things, and you get 0 things, you should get an empty container. I think that's a good rule of thumb, and it does seem to be the case the more I think about it.

Comment: @KennyTM updated my answer to reflect my changed opinion about it, thanks for the discussion!

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, an empty dict is falsy, so there's no problem there. But the idea of returning an empty dict leaves a bad taste in my mouth. I can't help but feel that returning an empty dict could hide errors that returning `None` would reveal. Still, it's just a gut feeling.

Comment: I would prefer returning an empty dictionary unless `None` and `{}` actually mean different things, in which case, I'd probably use an exception anyhow.

Answer (score -1):

```
Python supports returning multiple values. Hence, you can return a status of success along with an empty dictionary. The caller first verifies the return code and then uses the dictionary.

def result_none(choice):
    mydict = {}
    retcode = -1
    if choice == 'a':
        mydict['x']  = 100
        mydict['y']  = 1000
        retcode = 0
    return mydict, retcode

retcode, mydict = result_none('a')
if retcode == 0:
   <<use dictionary>>
```

Comment: The "status code" is pointless -- if you return an empty dictionary, you don't need the status code. If you return `None`, checking `mydict is None` or `retcode != 0` is essentially the same thing.